# Error WebService al llamar desde localhost

Tags: java, webservice

Tengo un problema con un `WebService` y espero que me puedan ayudar.

El **Web Service** está ublicado y funciona sin problemas, pero cuando intento depurar el código desde `localhost` me da error;

> INFORMACIÓN: Se ha completado la recarga de este Contexto ago 19, 2019
>   5:54:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke GRAVE:
>   El Servlet.service() para el servlet [jsp] en el contexto con ruta
>   [/PasarelaServidorSample] lanzó la excepción
>   [/sampleSolicitudFirmaPortTypeProxy/Result.jsp (línea: [10], columna:
>   [0]) El valor el atributo de clsae useBean
>   [es.manw.jp.definitions.SolicitudFirmaPortTypeProxy] es inválido.] con
>   causa raíz org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   /sampleSolicitudFirmaPortTypeProxy/Result.jsp (línea: [10], columna:
>   [0]) El valor el atributo de clsae useBean
>   [es.manw.jp.definitions.SolicitudFirmaPortTypeProxy] es inválido.     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1383)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UseBean.accept(Node.java:1186)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2389)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2441)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2447)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:470)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2389)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3667)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:257)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:385)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: [/sampleSolicitudFirmaPortTypeProxy/Result.jsp (línea: [10], columna: [0]) El valor el atributo de clsae useBean [es.manw.jp.definitions.SolicitudFirmaPortTypeProxy] es inválido.]

Comment: Gracias abrahamhs, a que crees que puede ser debido. ¿ a la configuracion del servidor en https ? Disculpa mi ignorancia, pero soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Sino pones el código es imposible saberlo.